# Webview page load success/failure status

Tags: android-webview

I need some help over webview page load status check either the page load success/failure. I know that the Web view  onReceivedError override method handles failure calls. But I'm in need to find the success status, and send the status back to another application.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally there is no implementation for that in Android WebView.

In this related ticket a lot of suitable workarounds using http-status:

[Get HTTP Status Code in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889020/get-http-status-code-in-android-webview)

You success case would then be the response of status code 200.