# How to get server response code for redirecting response on WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview

I have a `WebView` component, I have set a `WebViewClient` to it:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview);

webView.setWebViewClient(
         new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String newUrl) {

                       //Here, I handle the url redirecting.
                       //@newUrl is the redirected url

                       // How to get server response code here??

                }
         }
);
```

As you see above, my code handles redirecting url in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)`. It works fine. Sometimes, the redirected server response is an error code with error message, e.g. the server log is:

```
 < 400
 < Content-Type: text/plain
 Bad header value: 'name'
```

In above case, the `WebView` page shows "**Bad header value: 'name'**".

My question is, in my java code, how can I get the server response code (e.g. in above case **400**) of the redirecting response?

**==================== What I tried ==========================**

I tried to add `onReceivedError()` into `new WebViewClient(){...}`, to catch the error response, but the code does not get executed.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
        Log.v("onReceivedError:", errorCode+":"+description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now.. the only (proper) way i guess is not through java code.Infact,it is by injecting javascript into your webview which inturn would give you the response code.

See this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13993930/1221203)