# How to get http header status code in webview on android?

Tags: android, http, header, status

I want to get header status code in webview. For example if status code is 200, do it or status code is 404, do other thing. But I didn't get header status code. Is webview allow it? If it allows , how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get status code of the webpage loaded in android webveiw?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635634/is-there-a-way-to-get-status-code-of-the-webpage-loaded-in-android-webveiw)

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889020/get-http-status-code-in-android-webview/21609608#21609608) that used a simple HTTP request to check the status.  If status = 200 GOOD! Load remote URL to webview, else load local HTML page from assets.