# how to check if webview is encountering a "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" page?

Tags: java, android, webview

I've already setup a banner in my app to display a banner from my own website using a web view. but i want to be able to disable the banner whenever i remove the banner from the website. but the app displays a 404 page instead of showing nothing. is there a way to detect 404 and handle it in another way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889020/get-http-status-code-in-android-webview