# How to get the status codes exactly in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, http-status-codes, http-error

I wanna catch status code, like 401, 404, 500, etc. And handle things with different error codes. When I first used the `WebView`, I thought the error code param in the `onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)` callback is what I want. But unfortunately its the constant values that defined in `WebViewClient`. Yep, I have searched this question for a long time on the net, inclusive [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and community issues: [issue01](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=968), [issue02](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32755), [issue03](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82069), but it came to nothing. The only thing that I know is we can use `onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse)` callback after API 23. And I wrote codes below but it didn't works on Nexus 6p(system version: Android N, minSdkVersion: 15, targetSdkVersion: 24):

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        Log.d(TAG, error.getErrorCode() + ": " + error.getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        Log.d(TAG, failingUrl + "\t" + errorCode + ": " + description);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
        super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(errorResponse.getStatusCode()));
    }
}
```

I use `WebView` to load a url which needs a token, apparently it should callback the `onReceivedHttpError` and get the error code 401 through the `WebResourceResponse`, but there is not any log in the `logcat` when I run above codes in my device.

Please help or try to give some ideas about how to achieve this. I just don't know why to mark my question duplicate and don't even give a practical answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTTP Status Code in Android WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889020/get-http-status-code-in-android-webview)

Comment: @LeoSeccia I have seen the question and all answers, but there isn't a good way to resolve my question.

Comment: @AlexanderPonomarev from that question is your best bet and does not require API23

Comment: @LeoSeccia I have poor knowledge in JavaScript. I notice it and I will have a try. Thx. Is there a simple way to resolve?